# Error al hacer un insert en PHP

Tags: php, sql

sinceramente nose donde esta el error en mi Insert, es mas lo tengo idéntico a como esta en el manual de php y lo mas extraño que sucede que en dos ocasiones luego de tocar reiteradas veces el submit se guardaron.

```html
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    $dni = $_POST['dni'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $nacimiento = $_POST['nacimiento'];
    $provincias = $_POST['provincias'];
    $alta = $_POST['alta'];
    if ($dni!=null & $apellido!=null & $nombre!=null & $sexo!=null  & $nacimiento!=null  & $provincias!=null  & $alta!=null){
        if($consulta = mysqli_prepare($conexion,"INSERT INTO abonados (DNI, apellido, nombre, sexo, nacimiento, provincia, alta)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))
        {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta,'issisis',$dni,$apellido,$nombre,$sexo,$nacimiento,$provincias,$alta);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "algo pasa";
          die(mysqli_error($consulta)); 

        }
    }else{
        echo "mal";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta editada. Dado que, según dices, `$sexo` y `$provincias` podrian tene un valor `0`, he puesto para esas variables una comparación *type safe* que verifique si son de tipo `NULL`, así, la condición se cumplirá únicamente cuando dichas variables sean nulas: **`if ($dni && $apellido && $nombre && $nacimiento  && $alta && $sexo!==NULL && $provincias!==NULL){ //Resto del código`**

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pasa es que no es `mysqli_prepare`, tienes que poner `mysqli_stmt_prepare` y te mostraré algunas recomendaciones para que tu código sea más seguro.

**Ejemplo:**

Esto no basta, pero igual es importante:

```
<?php 
$post = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['post']);
```

Esto ayudará a evitar inyección sql y hacer más seguro tu código php y msqli:

```
$filter = filter_var($post, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

**Es importante la validación de los datos que van entrando como el de email y de tipo string**

```
$validarEmail = filter_var($post, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) 

$validarString = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{minCaracteres, maxCaracteres}+$/", $post);

if($validarString && $validarEmail){
 //true - sí, cumple
}else{
 //false - no cumple
}
```

usar isset() para verificar si la variable existe o no
ejemplo:

```
 if(isset($post)){
  //true
 }else{
  //false
 }
```

usar empty() para verificar si la variable es un campo vacío o que contiene algún caracter
elemplo:

```
 if(empty($post)){
   //campo vacío
 }else{
  // el campo no está vacío
 }
 
?>
```

En conclusión usar solo msqli_stmt en realidad si hace más segura la conexión con sql pero de igual forma hay que evitar a toda costa la inyección sql, ya que los mal intencionados siempre intentarán una forma de hacer las suya.

Comment: al haber cambiado  mysqli_prepare  por  mysqli_stmt_prepare, ahora me lanza este error  "mysqli_stmt_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, object given in" ... Respecto a las recomendaciones, las utilizare. @Daniel

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` no es necesario si se usas consultas preparadas **realmente**. Y no hay por qué usar `isset` y `empty` al mismo tiempo, con `empty` bastaría para comprobar ambas cosas, salvo un caso muy específico: cuando se trabaja con valores `false` o `0`.

Comment: podrías poner primero el `msqli_stmt...` antes del `if`, así : `$stmt = mysqli_stmt... if( $stmt ) { //no hay error } else { //error }`

Comment: @A.Cedano por eso eran recomendaciones de lo que podía usar para lo que necesitara en su código, por eso hice una explicación breve para cada tipo de función, y también un tipo de ayuda que sé que le servirá en algún momento.

Comment: @Daniel Nose como implementar lo que añadiste en tu segundo comentario.

Comment: @A.Cedano Paso a comentar dos cosas, la primera es que edite mi pregunta, la variable $provincia es un int, segundo que tanto esta ultima como la variable $sexo pueden pasar valores con 0 , hago esta aclaracion porque cuando dichas variables son distintas de 0 el codigo que pasaste funciona correctamente, pero al ser iguales a 0 entonces lanza el mensaje de que el post tiene valores nulos

Comment: @Ultimatux precisamente por eso dije que en caso de trabajar con posibles valores `0` o `false` habría que afinar el código (para esas variables en específico). Ahora reviso tu pregunta editada.

Answer (score 3):

En tu código faltan algunas cosas y otras no están implementadas correctamente:

1. Los valores no tienen por qué ser `null` cuando no son posteados. Usa el [operador de fusión de null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php) cuando creas las variables (a partir de PHP 7+, o un ternario en versiones anteriores).
2. El [operador de comparación AND](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php) se escribe como `&&` o como `AND`, no con una sola `&`.
3. Te falta verificar el estado de la conexión. Nada te asegura que siempre habrá conexión.
4. Te falta verificar que no hubo error en la ejecución del INSERT, no sólo en la preparación. El mismo puede ser correcto desde el punto de vista sintáctico, pero levantar un error de clave duplicada u otro en la ejecución. Son dos cosas distintas y como mysqli no tiene posibilidad de `try ... catch` debes verificar ambas cosas por separado.

Aplicando lo dicho el código quedaría así:

```
<?php
  include("conexion.php");
  $dni = $_POST['dni'] ?? NULL;
  /*
      Si tu versión de PHP es inferior a 7
      Tienes que cambiar todo a este estilo:
      $dni = !empty($_POST['dni']) ? $_POST['dni'] : NULL;
  */
  $apellido = $_POST['apellido'] ?? NULL;
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'] ?? NULL;
  $sexo = $_POST['sexo'] ?? NULL;
  $nacimiento = $_POST['nacimiento'] ?? NULL;
  $provincias = $_POST['provincias'] ?? NULL;
  $alta = $_POST['alta'] ?? NULL;
  if ($dni && $apellido && $nombre && $nacimiento  && $alta && $sexo!==NULL && $provincias!==NULL)
  {
      if ($conexion) 
      {
        $sql="INSERT INTO abonados (DNI, apellido, nombre, sexo, nacimiento, provincia, alta)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        if( $consulta = mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql) ) 
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta,'ississs',$dni,$apellido,$nombre,$sexo,$nacimiento,$provincias,$alta);
            if ( mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta) ) 
            {
              $msg=sprintf("Se insertaron %d filas",mysqli_affected_rows($conexion));
            } else {
              $msg=sprintf("Error ejecutando: %s",mysqli_error($conexion));
            }
        }
        else
        {
          $msg=sprintf("Error preparando la consulta: %s",mysqli_error($conexion));
        }
      }
      else
      {
        $msg="No hay conexion";
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      $msg="Hay valores nulos en el POST";
    }
    echo $msg;
?>
```

#### Post-Data

Al estar en fase de desarrollo he puesto mensajes de error internos. Eso te permitirá conocer directamente la causa del error. Considera cambiar esto por errores personalizados cuando el código pase a producción.

Answer (score 1):

Hice algunos cambios al código, espero que te ayude a resolver tu problema.

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

$dni = $_POST['dni'] ?? null;
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'] ?? null;
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'] ?? null;
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'] ?? null;
$nacimiento = $_POST['nacimiento'] ?? null;
$provincias = $_POST['provincias'] ?? null;
$alta = $_POST['alta'] ?? null;

if ($dni && $apellido && $nombre && $sexo && $nacimiento && $provincias  && $alta) 
{

  $dni = filter_var($dni, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  $apellido = filter_var($apellido, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $nombre = filter_var($nombre, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $sexo = filter_var($sexo, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  $nacimiento = filter_var($nacimiento, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $provincias = filter_var($provincias, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  $alta = filter_var($alta, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $validate = preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $nombre);

if($validate){
    echo "El nombre solo puede contener letras y números";
    return;
}

$stmt = $conexion->stmt_init();
$consulta = $stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO abonados (DNI, apellido, nombre, sexo, nacimiento, provincia, alta) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  if ($consulta) {
    $consulta->bind_param('issisis', $dni, $apellido, $nombre, $sexo, $nacimiento, $provincias, $alta);
    $consulta->execute();
       if ($consulta) {
         $consulta->close();
       } else {
         print_r("Error: " . $consulta->error);
         $consulta->close();
       }
    }else {
     print_r("Error al preparar la consulta: " . $consulta->error());
   }
} else {
  echo "Los campos están vacíos";
}
```